# How do I compile a .net solution and get the output?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am working on some automation.  I have a batch file that will compile .net solutions.  I wish to automate this but I am stuck.

Original file:

```
"B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "My_Types\My_Types.sln" /build >> ..\Output\Build.txt
```

I can get this to work with a modified file:

```
Compile = New Process()
With Compile.StartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .FileName = """C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\Build Test.bat"""
End With
bSuccess = Compile.Start()
strOutput = Compile.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Compile.WaitForExit()
MsgBox(strOutput)
```

Modified file

```
   "B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln" /build
```

But I can't get the next step to work.  It has something to do with the arguments.

```
Compile = New Process()
With Compile.StartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .FileName = "b:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
    '.Arguments = "C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln /build" 'Does nothing
    '.Arguments = """C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln"" /build" 'Does nothing
    '.Arguments = """""C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln /build""""" 'Opens visual studio and parses the path as two files.
    '.Arguments = """""""C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln"" /build""""" 'Opend the file but I get a message saying files can not be found but there are no files in the list.
    '.Arguments = """""""C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln"" ""/build""""""" 'Tried this because I couldnt think of anything else, fails to find the file "/build"
End With
bSuccess = Compile.Start()
strOutput = Compile.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Compile.WaitForExit()
MsgBox(strOutput)
```

Comment: Are you using ... PowerShell? VB.NET? You don't have a language tag, which would help guide answerers.

Comment: I didnt know there was another way to compile C# or VB.  Added the tags.

Comment: @Roger - How do I get the path to msbuild?  Like I mentioned, this is automation.  I get the path to devenv from the registry.  I also need to get the output.  Will msbuild return output through process start that devenv will not?

Comment: ... and now you have two language tags that don't make sense together. The code in your examples `Compile = new Process()...`. That looks like VB. Are you using VB.NET to start these processes? In that case, it is not a batch file; it is an executable program.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is not a command line program, and as such it cannot output to the standard output. However with /Out "LogFilename.txt" you can make it output to a log file instead. For example:

```
    "C:\Code\Intuitive Projects\My_Types\My_Types.sln" /build "Release|Any CPU" /Out C:\Temp\TempLog.txt
```

You can that open and parse the log file.

That said, if you can, use MSBuild.exe instead of DevEnv.exe. MSBuild is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v or the 64-bit version in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v. The examples that it outputs tell you all you need to know:

```
    MSBuild MyApp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
    MSBuild MyApp.csproj /t:Clean
                         /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5
```

It outputs to the standard output / standard error like you expect. The only weird thing is that if you have parentheses or dollar signs in one of the definitions you send with the /p argument, MSBuild will freak out in very weird ways. In those cases you should use DevEnv.exe.

Alternatively you can call MSBuild programmaticly this is a bit more involved however. See information on Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager to do that. Or look at the [CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to get really low level.